# What's the percentage/relationship of evaporative cooling applied to the liquid by an evaporating/expanding gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, evaporation, thermal-conduction

[image: Diagram of flash vessel, hot water pump, vacuum pump, and recirculation loop]

*The example below is simply to provide illustration of the problem. This isn't a homework question. I'm trying to visualize the relationship between liquid and gas at the boundary and I'd appreciate general resources as much as a detailed answer:*

Suppose you have an equilibrium of water and steam inside of a flash vessel being pumped out of with a vacuum pump, which removes the steam from the top, producing a strong vacuum in the tank, and being pumped into with near atmospheric boiling water from a liquid pump.

As the expanding gas provides ~4.2kJ (heat capacity of water at and below 1atm) of evaporative cooling to the liquid and gas, which percentage of the cooling power remains in the liquid, and which percentage of the evaporative cooling power is drawn out by the vacuum pump?

Is the heat capacity of water even important to the power of evaporative cooling provided by a boiling liquid?

Think of this from the perspective of how much power should be added back into the liquid to reheat it to 95C for a recirculation loop.

---

You can imagine a simpler system description, but more difficult problem, by thinking about a compressed air can and figuring out what percentage of cooling is applied to the nozzle and can by the escaping gas.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that new liquid water is being added to the system continuously to replace the water that evaporates?  Are we to assume that this water is initially at 95°C, or does it need to be heated from some lower supply temperature?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you are correct. The water is being constantly replaced in this example. The water is always at 95C and the only energy input in the recirculation is there to replenish the energy lost through evaporative cooling. This is a perfectly insulated system.